# NoClassDefFoundError when using Apache POI XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-poi

I'm currently working on reading an excel doc in with Apache POI and I'm getting a NoClassDefFound error during runtime for XSSFWorkbook when executing a main method through IntelliJ.

I have included the following in my build.gradle:

```
'org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.0',
'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.0'
```

(I've also only included poi-ooxml as it has a dependency on poi with no luck).

Both jars are successfully retrieved and when I check IntelliJ's classpath, both the poi-ooxml and poi jars show up.

General code used is very simple:

```java
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ExcelParser {

    public void parseWorkbook(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("D:\\downloads\\Book1.xlsx");
        ExcelParser p = new ExcelParser();
        p.parseWorkbook(file);
    }
}
```

And here is the classpath for main:

```
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.0.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.35" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-rds:1.11.327" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.592" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:1.11.592" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.592" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:2.2.6" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: software.amazon.ion:ion-java:1.0.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:1.11.592" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.7.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:2.6.7" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: joda-time:joda-time:2.8.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:4.1.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.18" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:1.06" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: commons-codec:commons-codec:1.12" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:3.1.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.9" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.7" level="project" />
```

Now, when I attempt to run this through a unit test using IntelliJ, the unit test properly executes.  Classpath for the test is the same as the main classpath with the addition of junit.  Executing the test through Gradle is also successful.  So something is either wrong with my classpath for main or there's an issue with IntelliJ, but I'm at a loss.  Any ideas?

Comment: How are you getting those jars from your *compile time* classpath onto your *runtime classpath* ?

Comment: You should add your build.gradle to the post, the problem could be there

Comment: I'm having the same issue. An alternative could be to run the project on Netbeans. I did it without any problem (using the same libraries), but when attempting to run it on IntelliJ, it doesn´t work.